# WSUS Looping 2 updates on 2003 servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, windows-update

Good afternoon, Hopefully I can articulate this so that people understand my problem.

We have WSUS on windows server 2008. We have 8 Windows 2003 servers. 
There is an update ready to install KB2982792. We install it then it says there is another update to install KB2728973. Then it says there is another update to install, again KB2982792. This goes on and on.

Talked to microsoft support and they confirmed that the update was infact installed and applied to the computer (Checking untrusted certifactions confirmed that for these updates) and their suggestion was to just "Hide update".

This is fine except on the WSUS server it still shows failed updates which is not okay with our policy.

I'm here to ask for help figuring this out and what I can do to trouble shoot it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: This was solved by deleting an old dependent update that wasn't needed any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by deleting an old dependent update that wasn't needed any more. –  Ericrobert just now   edit

Comment: Give more details please.